# Razor PageModel RedirectToRouteResult does not work when calling OnPost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I'm trying to implement simple Asp.net core web application login flow.

The LoginModel

```
namespace Trading_System.UI.Pages.Account
{
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {

        [BindProperty]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        private IUserManager m_userManager;

        public LoginModel(IUserManager userManager)
        {
            m_userManager = userManager;
        }

        public void OnGet(string returnUrl)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
        {
            var user = m_userManager.GetUser(Username, Password);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Username or password are invalid.";
                return Page();
            }

            var claims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserName)
            };

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);

            return new RedirectToRouteResult(ReturnUrl);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostLogout(string returnUrl)
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            return new RedirectToPageResult("/index");
        }
    }
}
```

The cshtml code of Login

```
@page
@model Account.LoginModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
}

<div class="login-page">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Please enter your credentials</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form method="post">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Username"></label>
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" asp-for="Username" autofocus>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Password"></label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" asp-for="Password" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                            </div>
                            @if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ErrorMessage))
                            {
                                <div class="alert alert-warning">@Model.ErrorMessage</div>
                            }
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm setting the ReturnUrl property when OnGet is called (for example "https://localhost:44389/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FSecretPage") But I've also tried to set it manually so the problem is not there.

After I'm pressing Login I get redirected to the login page no matter what is the ReturnUrl given (I can see in chrome the 302 response).
The url after the submit is "https://localhost:44389/Account/Login?Length=14"

What am I doing wrong? I just want to redirect back to the route I was at before redirected to the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RedirectToRouteResult` does a redirect to a *route* where a route is a named route that is configured through the MVC router.

As your example shows, the `ReturnUrl` that gets passed to your login action is a relative URL though: `/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FSecretPage`. So `ReturnUrl` is `"/SecretPage"`.

A relative URL is usually equal to a named route, so using `RedirectToRoute` will not work here. What you can do instead is return a `LocalRedirectResult`:

```
return LocalRedirect(ReturnUrl);
```